# Анимация css кнопки

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать анимацию этих кругов, чтобы от ширины кнопки расширялись до размеров на картинке?

Answer (score 4):

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  
  width: min(calc(9vw + 9vh), 130px);
  height: min(calc(9vw + 9vh), 130px);
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

div::after,
div::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0, 0.4);
  border-radius: 50%;
  
  animation: waves 2s both linear infinite;
}

div::after {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

button {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  transition: 0.2s;
  
  z-index: 1;
}

button:active {
  transform: scale(0.9);
}

div:hover::after,
div:hover::before {
  display: none;
}

@keyframes waves {
  from {
    transform: scale(0.9);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  40% {
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(2.5);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>Hypno Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Какие-то страшные круги...

Comment: @Qwertiy в смысле?

Comment: Пикселизация очень заметна... Была... Сейчас намного лучше, хотя в ответе ничего не менялось. Может хром глючит?

Comment: Всё, я понял. Запусти сниппет, проскролль страницу так, чтобы он оказался вне видимой области, а потом обратно. Круги станут жирными и пикселизованными.

Comment: @Qwertiy да. Почему?

Comment: Понятия не имею, просто вижу, что так работает.